# Range between two tuples of integers?

Tags: python-2.7, range, tuples

Tuples seem ideal for version-number comparisons (assuming only numeric elements, which is a given in my case). I have two version numbers in the form of tuples comprised of integers. Say those tuples are:

```
minver = (1,2,3)
maxver = (1,2,9)
```

is there a simple and elegant way to get the "range" from `minver` to `maxver` as a `list`? I.e. for the above case I would like to get a `list` like this:

```
[(1,2,3), (1,2,4), (1,2,5), (1,2,6), (1,2,7), (1,2,8), (1,2,9)]
```

(Note: it is also fine if the last element is missing from the list, i.e. if the returned range does *not* include the maximum value.)

The `range` function clearly does not work (expects integers), but I also don't want to rely on the tuples being exactly `x` elements (x = `3` in the above case).

For example if I have a `minver` `tuple` `(1,)` it should be treated like `(1,0,0)` if the `maxver` `tuple` contains three values/elements (such as `(1,2,3)`).

Any way of doing this in a pythonic way (that is elegant)?

Comment: So the edit begs the question: What is the range between `(1, 2)` and `(1, 3, 1)` (for instance)

Comment: @JonClements: aaaah ... now I got what you mean ... :) ... very good point, hadn't even thought of that. Let's assume a maximum is known for it and let's assume for now it's `9` then. Your answer gets me started, I *think*. Tinkering at the moment.

Comment: I'm just tweaking as well ;)

Comment: Okay - another answer that isn't limited to 0-9 is present - somewhat better than the old one I think

Comment: And if still interested - another answer that should be quite faster (if relevant for you, of course) :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay - it's 2:30am, so the principle is that you fix the maximum length and upper bound of anyone of the versions, then treat that as a base for the number... Convert your start and end to an int to act as a range, then have another function to convert back to tuple... Will need a bit of work, but fairly sound theory...

```
from itertools import izip_longest, chain

minver = (1, 1, 3)
maxver = (1, 3, 19)

def version_range(start, end):
    start, end = zip(*izip_longest(start, end, fillvalue=0))
    base = max(max(chain(start, end)), 9) + 1
    def _toint(seq, base):
        return sum(base ** n * val for n, val in enumerate(reversed(seq)))
    def _totuple(num, base, length):
        ret = []
        for n in (base ** i for i in reversed(range(length))):
            res, num = divmod(num, n)
            ret.append(res)
        return tuple(ret)
    for se in xrange(_toint(start, base), _toint(end, base) + 1):
        print _totuple(se, base, len(start))


version_range(minver, maxver)
```

Answer (score 1):

To make things even, it's 3:00am here :)

I think it is possible to achieve this without power `**` operations, which might get expensive for big numbers.

I've written this code for python 3, but it could be easily adopted for python 2.7.

The principle is to simply generate new version until we reach the maximum one.

Here's the code:

```
# Easier to work with lists (for me)
min_ver = [1,1,2]
max_ver = [2,3,4]

max_num = max(min_ver + max_ver)
orig_length = len(min_ver)


def increase(an_array, max_num):
    while an_array[-1] == max_num:
        an_array.pop()
    an_array[-1] += 1
    an_array += [0] * (orig_length - len(an_array))
    return an_array


def gen_range(start, end, max_num):
    while start != end:
        yield increase(start, max_num)


for version in gen_range(min_ver, max_ver, max_num):
    print(version)
```

Some comparison:

Using `**`:

```
C:\Work>python -mtimeit -s"import tuples2" "tuples2.version_range((1,1,1),(1,3,5));"
```

10000 loops, best of 3: **101** usec per loop

Using `increase`:

```
C:\Work>python -mtimeit -s"import tuples" "tuples.gen_range([1,1,1], [1,3,5], 5)"
```

1000000 loops, best of 3: **0.606** usec per loop